# How can I bring a value into scope of an internal method without breaking or rewriting method signatures of a lot of other classes?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, dependency-management

I have some code like so:

```
abstract class FieldsetManager
{
    function populateFieldset(Fieldset $fieldset)
    {}
}

class DataFieldsetManager extends FieldsetManager
{
    function populateFieldset(Fieldset $fieldset)
    {
        /**
         * The problem is with value of $ledgerID
         * How do I get $ledgerID into this scope?
         */
        $value = MySqlConnector::getMySql()
            ->query("select value from table where id = " . $ledgerID)
            ->getArray();
        $fieldset->get('data')->setValueOptions($value);
    }
}

class FormManager extends GenericRepository
{
    function populateForm(Form $form)
    {
        (new MotorFieldsetManager())->populateFieldset($form->get("motor"));
        (new DriveFieldsetManager())->populateFieldset($form->get("drive"));
        (new DataFieldsetManager())->populateFieldset($form->get("data"));
        (new SubmitFieldsetManager())->populateFieldset($form->get("submit"));
    }
}

/*
 * This code is located in my Controller:
 */
$ledgerId = $_SESSION['ledger_id'];
$form = new \Zend\Form\Form();
$formManager = new FormManager();
$formManager->populateForm($form);
```

Note the `$ledgerId` value in `DataFieldsetManager::populateFieldset()`.  The value of `$ledgerId` is originally stored in the SESSION variable and retrieved during application bootstrap (i.e. stored as a global variable)

My choices seem to be ...

1. Retrieve the value directly from the session again from within `DataFieldsetManager::populateFieldset()`
2. Reuse the global variable by passing it through the calling chain.  That is, I will need to rewrite `FormManager` method signatures to allow injection of `$ledgerId` (this can be done via __construct() or a setter method or via passing $ledgerId to `FormManager::populateForm()` and subsequently to `DataFieldsetManager::populateFieldset()`.  However, that breaks uniformity of code, i.e. `MotorFieldsetManager::populateFieldset()` method signature will remain unaffected, and without parameters, while `DataFieldsetManager::populateFieldset($ledgerId)` signature will now contain an extra parameter..

How would you handle this?

Answer (score -5):

The use of global variables could solve this problem.

```
$variable_name;  
public function something()
{
   Global $variable_name;  
    if ($this->link === null)
        $this->link = something::something();
    return $this->link;
}
```